# mongodb: sorting a numeric field on dynamic number

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I know that currently there is no possibility of sorting dynamically with mongodb. Although I have a task that needs to be solved:

I have a collection with > 1 Mio docs. Each doc contains a field named "group_id", which contains a number between 1 and 200. Now during process I want to find() all docs fitting into a certain condition AND being sorted in a way that all docs with a given group_id should come first and all others afterwards. All given numbers (1-200) could be questioned.

How could I precalculated a field depending on "group_id" so that I get the desired sorting order on run-time? Is that possible? I want to avoid having an array with 200 members (199 = false and 1 =  true), because that would mean 200 indexes also.

Any ideas on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are right this is not completely viable in standard querying before 2.2 (where this would be accomplished using the aggregation framework most likely). You could solve this via MR but it could be slower, personally I would do this client side (which can be quite fast) how many returned records are you expecting?

Comment: You are asking the right question and the answer is the reason for my question ;-) : too much! The number of records can be > 1.000 and I only wanted to return around 50 or so (paging client-side).

Comment: @heinob: Is there a specific order to the `group_id`s (i.e. ascending), or would this change depending on the query?  Not entirely  clear how you are intending to use the group_id.

Comment: What if you shot off two queries, one for the group_id then one for all others? Since this group_id will always be on top you could calculate the range of the paging and find out when you will need new results from the db from a second query requesting all that are not this group_id

Comment: @Stennie: The group_id's have no order. Concerning the sorting order is additionally irrelevent because I only want to have the order [group_id === <specific number>, group_id !== <specific number>]

Comment: Could it be a solution to create a second field "group_id_obj" that contains an object with the group_id as its property and 1 as value  (i.e. {"123": 1}. I would now create an index with {group_id_obj: 1} and do sorting by sort:{group_id_obj.<specific numer>:1} (i.e. sort:{group_id_obj.123: 1}). Would that solve my problem?

Comment: I think @Sammaye's suggestion of two queries would be the better fit.  You can't do a sort by {`group_id_obj.<specific number>'} as that implies your original problem of 200 fields to index.